# Jquery Validation in table rows (generated rows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I have a page with a form, and a table under the form. In the table are multiple rows, generated from data in my controller. Each row is also an editable record, instantiating its own form on click of the Edit button. I'm trying to validate the individual rows in the table, but my jquery doesn't seem to fire off at all, so the validation fails entirely.

The code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Bootstrap.Base.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CampaignViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Modify Campaign Template
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Modify Campaign Template</h2>
    <form action="/CampaignBuilder/ModifyCampaignTemplate/<%=Model.CampaignTemplate.CampaignTemplate_id %>" id="form1" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <!-- REMOVED TO FOCUS ON THE REPEATER FORM -->
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <a href="/CampaignBuilder/AddNewTaskTemplate/<%=Model.CampaignTemplate.CampaignTemplate_id%>">Add new task</a><br/>

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Step</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Task Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Assign to CCR</th>
            <th>Dynamic</th>
            <th>Days</th>
            <th>Email Template</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <%
            if (Model.CampaignTaskTemplate != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.CampaignTaskTemplates)
                {
                    if (item.CampaignTaskTemplate_id != Model.CampaignTaskTemplate.CampaignTaskTemplate_id)
                    {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= item.StepID %></td>
            <td><%= Model.GetTypeName(item.Type) %></td>
            <td><%= item.Name %></td>
            <td><%= item.Description %></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" <% if (item.AssignToCCR)
                                          { %>Checked<% } %> disabled /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" <% if (item.DynamicTiming)
                                          { %>Checked<% } %> disabled /></td>
            <td><%= item.Days %></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="/CampaignBuilder/ModifyCampaignTemplate/<%= Model.CampaignTemplate.CampaignTemplate_id %>?task_id=<%= item.CampaignTaskTemplate_id %>">Edit</a>
            &nbsp;<a href="/CampaignBuilder/DeleteCampaignTaskTemplate/<%= item.CampaignTaskTemplate_id %>">Delete</a>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <%          }
                    else
                    {
        %>
        <form method="post" id="rowForm" name="rowForm" action="/CampaignBuilder/ModifyCampaignTaskTemplate/<%= item.CampaignTaskTemplate_id %>">
            <tr bgcolor="#f0f7e7">
                <td>
                    <select name="selStepID" style="width: auto;">
                        <% for (int i = 1; i <= Model.CampaignTaskTemplates.Count(); i++) { %><option <% if (i == item.StepID) { %>selected<% } %>><%= i %></option><% } %>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="selTaskType" name="selTaskType" style="width: auto;">
                        <option value="0">Reminder</option>
                        <option value="1">Email</option>
                        <option value="2">Pop-By</option>
                        <option value="3">Call</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtTaskName" id="txtTaskName" value="<%= item.Name %>" maxlength="255" placeholder="Task Name" required /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtTaskDescription" id="txtTaskDescription" value="<%= item.Description %>" maxlength="255" placeholder="Task Description" /></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkAssignToCCR" <% if (item.AssignToCCR)
                                                                    { %>Checked<% } %> /></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkDynamic" <% if (item.DynamicTiming)
                                                                { %>Checked<% } %> /></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="txtDays" value="<%= item.Days %>" style="width: 50px" maxlength="4" max="365" min="-365" required /></td>
                <td>
                    <% if (item.Type == 1 && item.EmailTemplate_id > 0)
                       { %>
                    <a href="/CampaignBuilder/AddEditEmailTemplate?EmailTemplateId=<%= item.EmailTemplate_id %>&TaskTemplateId=<%= item.CampaignTaskTemplate_id %>">Edit</a>
                    <% }
                       else if (item.Type == 1 && item.EmailTemplate_id == 0)
                       { %>
                    <a href="/CampaignBuilder/AddNewTaskTemplate2/<%= item.CampaignTaskTemplate_id %>">Add</a>
                    <% } %>
                </td>
                <td nowrap>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn color" name="fmrTwoSubmit" id="fmrTwoSubmit" />
                    <input type="button" value="cancel" class="btn" onclick="window.location.href ='/CampaignBuilder/ModifyCampaignTemplate/<%= Model.CampaignTemplate.CampaignTemplate_id %>'" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">$('#selTaskType option[value=<%= item.Type %>]').attr("selected", "selected");</script>
        <%          }
                }
            }
            else
            { 
                foreach (var item in Model.CampaignTaskTemplates)
                {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= item.StepID %></td>
            <td><%= Model.GetTypeName(item.Type) %></td>
            <td><%= item.Name %></td>
            <td><%= item.Description %></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" <% if (item.AssignToCCR) { %>Checked<% } %> disabled="disabled" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" <% if (item.DynamicTiming) { %>Checked<% } %> disabled="disabled" /></td>
            <td><%= item.Days %></td>
            <td></td>
            <td nowrap>
                <a href="/CampaignBuilder/ModifyCampaignTemplate/<%= Model.CampaignTemplate.CampaignTemplate_id %>?task_id=<%= item.CampaignTaskTemplate_id %>">Edit</a>
                &nbsp;<a href="/CampaignBuilder/DeleteCampaignTaskTemplate/<%= item.CampaignTaskTemplate_id %>">Delete</a>&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <%      }
           } %>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content7" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdditionalScripts" runat="server">
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.tinysort.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/additional-methods.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#emailSearchArea').hide();
            $('#userNotFound').hide();

            $('#form1').validate({
                rules: {
                    txtName: {
                        required: true
                        , maxlength: 255
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    txtName: {
                        required: "Please enter a Campain Name.",
                        maxlength: "Campain Name may be no longer than 255 characters."
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#rowForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    "txtTaskName": {
                        required: true,
                        maxlength: 255
                    },
                    "txtTaskDescription": {
                        maxlength: 255
                    },
                    "txtDays": {
                        required: true,
                        max: 365,
                        min: -365,
                        TextOnly: "^[0-9\-]+$"
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    "txtTaskName": {
                        required: "Please enter a Task Name.",
                        maxlength: "Task Name may be no longer than 255 characters."
                    },
                    "txtTaskDescription": {
                        maxlength: "Description may be no longer than 255 characters."
                    },
                    "txtDays": {
                        required: "Please enter the number of days.",
                        max: "Days must be between -365 and 365.",
                        min: "Days must be between -365 and 365.",
                        TextOnly: "Days must be a whole number between -365 and 365."
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#selType option[value=<%=Model.CampaignTemplate.CampaignType%>]').attr("selected", "selected");
            $('#selTarget option[value=<%=Model.CampaignTemplate.Target %>]').attr("selected", "selected");
        });

        $("#selOwner").change(function () {
            var value = this.value;
            if (this.value == "4") {
                $('#emailSearchArea').show();
            } else {
                $('#emailSearchArea').hide();
            }
        });

        function ValidateEmail() {
            $('#validateButton').html('Loading...')
            $('#userMessage').html("Searching for user...");
            $('#btnSave').hide();
            $.post('/CampaignBuilder/AgentSearch', { email: $('#txtEmail').val() }, function (data) {
                if (data.error == false) {
                    $('#newOwnerId').val(data.id);
                    $('#userMessage').html("Save to set owner to: " + data.fullname);
                } else {
                    $('#newOwnerId').val('');
                    $('#userMessage').html("User not found.");
                }

                $('#btnSave').show();
                $('#validateButton').html('Validate');
            });
        };

        var replaceRegex = /[^\u0000-\u00FF]/g;
        $("#txtDescription").keypress(function (e) {
            if (replaceRegex.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which))) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
        $("#txtDescription").on('paste', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var text = $("#txtDescription").val();
                $("#txtDescription").val(text.replace(replaceRegex, ''));
            }, 100);
        });
        $("#txtName").keypress(function (e) {
            if (replaceRegex.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which))) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
        $("#txtName").on('paste', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var text = $("#txtName").val();
                $("#txtName").val(text.replace(replaceRegex, ''));
            }, 100);
        });
        $("#txtTaskDescription").keypress(function (e) {
            if (replaceRegex.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which))) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
        $("#txtTaskDescription").on('paste', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var text = $("#txtTaskDescription").val();
                $("#txtTaskDescription").val(text.replace(replaceRegex, ''));
            }, 100);
        });
        $("#txtTaskName").keypress(function (e) {
            if (replaceRegex.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which))) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
        $("#txtTaskName").on('paste', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var text = $("#txtTaskName").val();
                $("#txtTaskName").val(text.replace(replaceRegex, ''));
            }, 100);
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

The form in the repeater loop in the table is $("#rowForm"). That's the form I'm trying to validate.

Comment: Add edit template and respective validator like required field, custom and so on....

Answer (score 0):

Here I have a sample code which works for me:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="Day" HeaderText="Day" UniqueName="DayTemplateColumn">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("DayDisplay")%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadDropDownList Width="100px" runat="server" ID="DayDropDown" class="course-dropdown" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDay" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="RadGridValidationGroup"
                            CssClass="required" ControlToValidate="DayDropDown" ErrorMessage="Select Day" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

By writing similar code, it should works in this case as well.

Comment: If I were working with a) Telerik tools {which I try never to do}, or b) gridviews, an edit template would be a valid thing to use. But I'm not building in that kind of app. The "edit template" is in the Foreach loop, in the Else clause, in the code. There should be a way to validate that without rebuilding the entire page to use a methodology that isn't used anywhere else in my app.

Comment: Did you debug within the developer tools and what the log says over there?

Comment: Debug tools skips right over the validate call like it's not even there.

Comment: Does form1 validates?

Comment: Yeah, it validates fine. And I just figured out how to make the inline form validate as well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be decently simple: Move the validation into the row with the form.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Bootstrap.Base.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CampaignViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Modify Campaign Template
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Modify Campaign Template</h2>
    <form action="/CampaignBuilder/ModifyCampaignTemplate/<%=Model.CampaignTemplate.CampaignTemplate_id %>" id="form1" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <!-- REMOVED TO FOCUS ON THE REPEATER FORM -->
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <p>Add or edit existing tasks. To edit, click in the row to enable edit mode. If task is "Dynamic", the days field will indicate the number of days due AFTER the previous Step ID task. Otherwise, the Days field will indicate the number of days due after the campaign is scheduled.</p>

    <a href="/CampaignBuilder/AddNewTaskTemplate/<%=Model.CampaignTemplate.CampaignTemplate_id%>">Add new task</a><br/>

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Step</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Task Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Assign to CCR</th>
            <th>Dynamic</th>
            <th>Days</th>
            <th>Email Template</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <%
            if (Model.CampaignTaskTemplate != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.CampaignTaskTemplates)
                {
                    if (item.CampaignTaskTemplate_id != Model.CampaignTaskTemplate.CampaignTaskTemplate_id)
                    {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= item.StepID %></td>
            <td><%= Model.GetTypeName(item.Type) %></td>
            <td><%= item.Name %></td>
            <td><%= item.Description %></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" <% if (item.AssignToCCR) { %>Checked<% } %> disabled /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" <% if (item.DynamicTiming) { %>Checked<% } %> disabled /></td>
            <td><%= item.Days %></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><a href="/CampaignBuilder/ModifyCampaignTemplate/<%= Model.CampaignTemplate.CampaignTemplate_id %>?task_id=<%= item.CampaignTaskTemplate_id %>">Edit</a>
            &nbsp;<a href="/CampaignBuilder/DeleteCampaignTaskTemplate/<%= item.CampaignTaskTemplate_id %>">Delete</a>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <%          }
                    else
                    {
        %>
        <form method="post" id="rowForm" name="rowForm" action="/CampaignBuilder/ModifyCampaignTaskTemplate/<%= item.CampaignTaskTemplate_id %>">
            <tr bgcolor="#f0f7e7">
                <td>
                    <select name="selStepID" style="width: auto;">
                        <% for (var i = 1; i <= Model.CampaignTaskTemplates.Count(); i++) { %><option <% if (i == item.StepID) { %>selected<% } %>><%= i %></option><% } %>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="selTaskType" name="selTaskType" style="width: auto;">
                        <option value="0">Reminder</option>
                        <option value="1">Email</option>
                        <option value="2">Pop-By</option>
                        <option value="3">Call</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtTaskName" id="txtTaskName" value="<%= item.Name %>" maxlength="255" placeholder="Task Name" required /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtTaskDescription" id="txtTaskDescription" value="<%= item.Description %>" maxlength="255" placeholder="Task Description" /></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkAssignToCCR" <% if (item.AssignToCCR) { %>Checked<% } %> /></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkDynamic" <% if (item.DynamicTiming) { %>Checked<% } %> /></td>
                <td><input type="number" name="txtDays" value="<%= item.Days %>" style="width: 70px" maxlength="4" max="365" min="-365" required /></td>
                <td>
                    <% if (item.Type == 1 && item.EmailTemplate_id > 0) { %>
                    <a href="/CampaignBuilder/AddEditEmailTemplate?EmailTemplateId=<%= item.EmailTemplate_id %>&TaskTemplateId=<%= item.CampaignTaskTemplate_id %>">Edit</a>
                    <% } else if (item.Type == 1 && item.EmailTemplate_id == 0) { %>
                    <a href="/CampaignBuilder/AddNewTaskTemplate2/<%= item.CampaignTaskTemplate_id %>">Add</a>
                    <% } %>
                </td>
                <td nowrap>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn color" name="fmrTwoSubmit" id="fmrTwoSubmit" />
                    <input type="button" value="cancel" class="btn" onclick="window.location.href ='/CampaignBuilder/ModifyCampaignTemplate/<%= Model.CampaignTemplate.CampaignTemplate_id %>'" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $('#selTaskType option[value=<%= item.Type %>]').attr("selected", "selected");
            //Moved the Validation here, so it's in each row.
            $("#rowForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    "txtTaskName": {
                        required: true,
                        maxlength: 255
                    },
                    "txtTaskDescription": {
                        maxlength: 255
                    },
                    "txtDays": {
                        required: true,
                        max: 365,
                        min: -365,
                        TextOnly: "^[0-9\-]+$"
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    "txtTaskName": {
                        required: "Please enter a Task Name.",
                        maxlength: "Task Name may be no longer than 255 characters."
                    },
                    "txtTaskDescription": {
                        maxlength: "Description may be no longer than 255 characters."
                    },
                    "txtDays": {
                        required: "Please enter the number of days.",
                        max: "Days must be between -365 and 365.",
                        min: "Days must be between -365 and 365.",
                        TextOnly: "Days must be a whole number between -365 and 365."
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
        <%          }
                }
            }
            else
            { 
                foreach (var item in Model.CampaignTaskTemplates)
                {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= item.StepID %></td>
            <td><%= Model.GetTypeName(item.Type) %></td>
            <td><%= item.Name %></td>
            <td><%= item.Description %></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" <% if (item.AssignToCCR) { %>Checked<% } %> disabled="disabled" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" <% if (item.DynamicTiming) { %>Checked<% } %> disabled="disabled" /></td>
            <td><%= item.Days %></td>
            <td></td>
            <td nowrap>
                <a href="/CampaignBuilder/ModifyCampaignTemplate/<%= Model.CampaignTemplate.CampaignTemplate_id %>?task_id=<%= item.CampaignTaskTemplate_id %>">Edit</a>
                &nbsp;<a href="/CampaignBuilder/DeleteCampaignTaskTemplate/<%= item.CampaignTaskTemplate_id %>">Delete</a>&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <%      }
            } %>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content7" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdditionalScripts" runat="server">
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.tinysort.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/additional-methods.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#emailSearchArea').hide();
            $('#userNotFound').hide();

            $('#form1').validate({
                rules: {
                    txtName: {
                        required: true
                        , maxlength: 255
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    txtName: {
                        required: "Please enter a Campain Name.",
                        maxlength: "Campain Name may be no longer than 255 characters."
                    }
                }
            });



            $('#selType option[value=<%=Model.CampaignTemplate.CampaignType%>]').attr("selected", "selected");
            $('#selTarget option[value=<%=Model.CampaignTemplate.Target %>]').attr("selected", "selected");
        });

        $("#selOwner").change(function () {
            var value = this.value;
            if (this.value == "4") {
                $('#emailSearchArea').show();
            } else {
                $('#emailSearchArea').hide();
            }
        });

        function ValidateEmail() {
            $('#validateButton').html('Loading...')
            $('#userMessage').html("Searching for user...");
            $('#btnSave').hide();
            $.post('/CampaignBuilder/AgentSearch', { email: $('#txtEmail').val() }, function (data) {
                if (data.error == false) {
                    $('#newOwnerId').val(data.id);
                    $('#userMessage').html("Save to set owner to: " + data.fullname);
                } else {
                    $('#newOwnerId').val('');
                    $('#userMessage').html("User not found.");
                }

                $('#btnSave').show();
                $('#validateButton').html('Validate');
            });
        };

        var replaceRegex = /[^\u0000-\u00FF]/g;
        $("#txtDescription").keypress(function (e) {
            if (replaceRegex.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which))) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
        $("#txtDescription").on('paste', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var text = $("#txtDescription").val();
                $("#txtDescription").val(text.replace(replaceRegex, ''));
            }, 100);
        });
        $("#txtName").keypress(function (e) {
            if (replaceRegex.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which))) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
        $("#txtName").on('paste', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var text = $("#txtName").val();
                $("#txtName").val(text.replace(replaceRegex, ''));
            }, 100);
        });
        $("#txtTaskDescription").keypress(function (e) {
            if (replaceRegex.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which))) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
        $("#txtTaskDescription").on('paste', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var text = $("#txtTaskDescription").val();
                $("#txtTaskDescription").val(text.replace(replaceRegex, ''));
            }, 100);
        });
        $("#txtTaskName").keypress(function (e) {
            if (replaceRegex.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode || e.which))) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
        $("#txtTaskName").on('paste', function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var text = $("#txtTaskName").val();
                $("#txtTaskName").val(text.replace(replaceRegex, ''));
            }, 100);
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```